# equivalence of 1-norm and 2-norm Gaussian widths

Tags: probability-theory

Source: Vershynin, High Dimensional Probability, Exercise 7.6.1.

Let $T\subset R^n$ and $g\sim N(0,I_n)$. We define the 1-norm and 2-norm Gaussian widths as follows:

$h(T)^2:=\mathbb E\sup_{t\in T} \langle g,t \rangle^2$ and $w(T):=\mathbb E\sup_{t\in T} \langle g,t \rangle$. I want to prove the following inequality:

$$h(T-T)\le w(T-T)+C\text{diam}(T), $$

where $T-T:=\{x-y:x,y\in T\}.$

The hint says one can use the Gaussian concentration for this bound. I think he meant [image]

I have thought about taking $f(y):=\sup_{x\in T-T}\langle y,x \rangle$, but I feel like we can't get it straightforwardly. Did I miss anything?

Comment: This has already been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3341449/relation-between-gaussian-width-and-its-squared-version).

Comment: @VHarisop Thanks!